# Registration with Email and Password in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, email, registration

I am working in an iOS application and I am asked to create a user registration with email and password. My friend told me that Apple rejects application if we prompt user to provide is personal information such as Phone number , email address and date of birth. So I am in a dilemma if I implement registration with email and password the apple will reject it or not. Need your suggesions

Thanks

Comment: apple will not reject your application, if your application really need this... means you are using this information in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not reject your application if it contains a user registration and your app needs the personal data. "Big" apps like Facebook or Twitter are in the app store and you have to sign up.

Of course there are a few limitations:

- your app has to function without **sharing** personal information
  [image]
- you have to include a privacy policy
  [image]

Further information can be found here: [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy)